# Any difference between Chrome on Mac and Chrome on Windows?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, position

I am studying CSS3 and HTML5 and trying to develop a simple homepage. Since I have only Mac interface in my house so I couldn't check any differences on windows.

But one day, one of my acquaintances told me that there is a pixel difference between browsers which I didn't know at all. Then I checked my page and it appeared to be wrong.

Even though it was same resolution as I set, Chrome on Mac showed me an appropriate position of several buttons but Chrome on Windows didn't.

Their position was quite different and ruined the design. How can I fix this problem? or is it normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to web design.

Comment: Thanks. I've heard of the 'cross browser' but didn't know that there would be a different result even though they are same browsers! is it natural in the reason of mac and windows' difference?

Comment: You can check if the program versions are different. But yes, if you want to target different platforms, you will need to test on those platforms! And then there's your question, "How can I fix this problem", without showing us your website. That is going to be difficult.

Comment: You might also want to get a virtual machine or three with the browsers you intend to support and check there.

Comment: I appreciate you guys' thoughtful comments. really helpful. thanks.

Comment: I'm glad so much was accomplished in the comments, but was this problem solved? If so, someone (even the asker), please answer and accept that answer.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I will try to summarize everything into an answer.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I didn't fix my issues yet, people here gave a key to solve them. You should read the summary below.

Comment: Should this be in webmasters instead of stack overflow

Comment: Hoon, note I said -if- it had been solved.

Comment: Same here. Got this issue on my floating divs. It renders differently in Chrome on Windows vs Chrome on Mac. In Mac, it displays just fine, but in Windows OS, my layout was ruined. Pretty weird as it's just basic CSS.

Comment: May be Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461106/2073920

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Developing a site that is the same on every combination of operating system and browser is no easy task.  It has personally added many hours to my development time trying to fix the issues.

There are several tools out there that try to help you with this task, such as [Cross Browser Testing](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/).  Or you can manually test it by installing the browsers on your machine.  It is also common to use virtual machines to test your website on other platforms.  [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) is popular.

Using cross browser libraries can also aid in this.  Such as [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery), which is very popular.  This [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser) lists more information on the subject, in general.

Answer (score 2):

Difference is not in Chrome, but difference is in Mac and Windows.
Here, you can detect the `userAgent` and add the appropriate `class` to the `body` tag (with jQuery):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') > 0){
  jQuery('body').addClass('mac-os');
 } else {
  jQuery("body").addClass("pc");
 }
});
```

After detecting userAgent, you can write css specially for Mac and Window and their browsers too.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 chrome and firefox behave differently depending on the operating system. I built a site recently, and on latest chrome and firefox versions one page was rendering OK in windows, while on macOS and ubuntu, it had a small glitch. The elements that are supposed to be inline were displaying horizontally in certain states.