# Difference between Chrome for iOS and Chrome for Android

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome

As the title says: What is the difference between Chrome for Android and Chrome for iOS.

I've done a bit of research between the two but couldn't find any recent information regarding the subject.
The reason for doing this research is because I'm looking into the compatibility between mobile browsers for certain Web API's. For this I'm using [caniuse.com](https://www.caniuse.com), which only displays Chrome for android but not iOS.

I am aware that Chrome for iOS is not being executed by the UIWebView any longer (iOS >= 8), and it now makes use of [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview).

So are Chrome for Android and Chrome for iOS the same or is there still a difference between these mobile browsers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After doing some more research and asking a few questions to some developers, I got my answer.
The browser, Chrome for Android makes use of the Blink engine. Chrome for iOS makes use of the WebKit engine. These are both a fork of the [KHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KHTML) layout engine.

Because of the strict rules that are in place at Apple. All the browsers that are installable for iOS make use of the WebKit engine instead of the their original layout engine.

Comment: Does this mean that Chrome for iOS does not support the same features as Chrome for Android ? So for example in Chrome for Android I can save credentials, check the batterie, make the phone vibrate or create notifications that are shown in the status bar. Is all of this possible on Chrome for iOS or does Chrome for iOS has the same feature support as Safari for iOS?

Comment: Yes, you interpreted that correctly. The mobile webbrowsers for iOS are closed off to use other engines, because of this they make use the engines that are present in the Safari browser. Which results in a difference of available web API's for iOS and Android browsers. So it's the latter option, Chrome for iOS has the same web API's available as the iOS Safari webbrowsers.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know, thanks. Always tricky to investigate something like this when you dont own an iPhone.

Answer (score 26):

```
╔═══════════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║        Chrome         ║ Rendering Engine ║   JavaScript Engine   ║
╠═══════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ iOS                   ║ iOS WebKit       ║ Nitro(JavaScriptCore) ║
║ Android/Windows/Linux ║ Blink            ║ V8                    ║
╚═══════════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

In addition to @Innominatum answer, Note that Chrome for Android/Windows/Linux uses V8 JavaScript engine while Chrome for iOS has to use Nitro engine (same engine that powers Safari)

> In accordance with Apple's requirements for browsers released through
>   their App Store, iOS version of Chrome uses the iOS WebKit – which is
>   Apple's own mobile rendering engine and components, developed for
>   their Safari browser – therefore it is restricted from using Google's
>   own V8 JavaScript engine

So chrome and even Firefox behaves fundamentally same as Safari on iOS.
That's why https://caniuse.com shows just one support table (iOS Safari) for iOS

**References:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198375/why-is-it-impossible-for-google-to-port-v8-along-with-chromes-codebase-in-c-obj

https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1551

https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/3869

Comment: To summarize, Apple restricts their users to the sole browsing experience they designed.