# overflow displays different view in MacBook Pro 15

Tags: html, css

content is not overflow ,it behaves normally in MacBook Pro 13 but Chrome in MacBook Pro 15，it will have a scrollbar under the inner box, why did it happen?

```css
.box{
  overflow:scroll hidden;
}
.inner{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Macbook pro 15 have a scrollbar :

[image: Macbook pro 15 have a scrollbar]

Comment: because it's not `scroll hidden` it's just `hidden`

Comment: here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzvwn7se/)

Comment: I would like have a horizontal scrollbar when content is overflow

Comment: put it on auto. Your overflow

Comment: Can you please accept my asnwer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853497/any-difference-between-chrome-on-mac-and-chrome-on-windows